# Calculating a limit involving the integer part of a number

Tags: limits

Let $\lambda$ be a number such that $|\lambda| > 1$ and $n \ge 1$. I read in a book the following relation:
$$\underset{n \to \infty}{limsup} \frac{\log (2 [|\lambda|^n] + 1)}{n} = \log |\lambda|.$$
Can someone explain me how this result came out?

Comment: Are the absolute value signs supposed to represent the integer part of $\lambda$?  We would use $\lfloor \lambda \rfloor$ to represent the floor function.

Comment: [-4.3] = -5, but [|-4.3|] = [4.3] = 4.

Comment: MathJax hint:  putting a backslash before functions like log and things like lim gets the proper font and spacing.  So \log x gives $\log x$ compared with log x which gives $log x$  I had missed the brackets you were using for the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, the integer part cannot change the number by more than $1$ and being inside the log it will make almost no difference at all.  I will take $\lambda \gt 1$ so I don't have to type the absolute value signs.  To be a bit more formal
$$\frac {\log(2\lfloor \lambda^n \rfloor+1)}n\lt \frac {\log(2\lambda^n+1)}n=\frac{\log(2)+n\log(\lambda)+\log\left(\frac{2\lambda^n+1}{2\lambda^n}\right)}n\to \log(\lambda)
$$